# Nested if Statement does not follow "map"

Tags: c#

I have a bit of an issue with some nested if statements. Here is what it looks like:

```
if (selectedlocat == "")
{
    if (selectedfield == "")
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
else
{
    if (selectedfield == "")
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

It does not follow the "map" correctly. For some reason it always goes to the else statement in the else statement at the bottom. I know this because it gives me an error in that area, when it was never supposed to even get to that part of the code.

What is going on, and how can I fix it?

******EDIT*****

Alright, so let me do a little clarification:

It is in a razor webpage, so debugging does me no good until I run into the error.

The values are truly empty, I have a foreach inside of each if and else

The whole story:

I have a website in which I get data and I conditionally show it based on what the dropdown form is. the reason I think that it is in the nesting is that I had it working with one dropdown, but when I added the second one, I had to make it conditional. Here is the full code:

```
        @{
           if (selectedlocat == "")
           {
               if (selectedfield == "")
               {
                   foreach (var row1 in db.Query(querypeople + order))
                                    
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center; width: 110px">@row1.Last_Name, @row1.First_Name </td>
                            <td>@row1.Firm_Name</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center"><a href="http://@row1.Website">@row1.Website</a></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">@row1.Phone_Office</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">@row1.City_Phys</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                   foreach (var row2 in db.Query(querypeople + where + field + selectedfield + app + order))
                                    
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center; width: 110px">@row2.Last_Name, @row2.First_Name </td>
                            <td>@row2.Firm_Name</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center"><a href="http://@row2.Website">@row2.Website</a></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">@row2.Phone_Office</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">@row2.City_Phys</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
               }

           }
           else
           {
               if (selectedfield == "")
               {
                   foreach (var row3 in db.Query(querypeople + where + city + selectedlocat + app + order))
                                    
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center; width: 110px">@row3.Last_Name, @row3.First_Name </td>
                            <td>@row3.Firm_Name</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center"><a href="http://@row3.Website">@row3.Website</a></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">@row3.Phone_Office</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">@row3.City_Phys</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var row4 in db.Query(querypeople + where + city + selectedlocat + app + and + field + selectedfield + app + order))
                                    
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center; width: 110px">@row4.Last_Name, @row4.First_Name </td>
                            <td>@row4.Firm_Name</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center"><a href="http://@row4.Website">@row4.Website</a></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">@row4.Phone_Office</td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">@row4.City_Phys</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
         
          }
    }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: what values you are getting Passed and Why not to use `String.IsNullorEmpty` rather than "".

Comment: _"I know this because it gives me an error"_ Use the debugger instead of waiting for errors.

Comment: Have you debugged it?  Is selectedlocat != "" and selectedfield != ""?

Comment: What do you mean 'map' - 'pattern'? Map means something else in C# usually.

Comment: @joshua: Maybe the OP doesn't *want* to handle `null` that way? There's nothing wrong with using this code for an empty string...

Comment: Clearly `selectedlocat` is not "" and `selectedfield` is not "".

Comment: @JonSkeet There may be chances of getting wrong due to reference comparison if `operand` is of type `Object`. So `String.IsNullorEmpty` will avoid OP passing as object :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: If that were the problem, your solution would fail to compile. (`String.IsNullOrEmpty` only accepts a value of type `string`, not `object`.) In other words, while it's *possible* that you've identified a problem, that isn't the solution.

Comment: @Tim, no, don't use the debugger. Use unit tests. Debugging is the bad old way.

Comment: @DavidArno Your unit tests tell you on which line you have an error?

Comment: @DavidArno To really understand HOW code words rather than just if it DOES work - and indeed how it doesn't work if the unit test fails -  there's no substitute for single-stepping all new code in a debugger. You should of course also write unit tests, but it's bollocks to just say "debugging is the bad old way".

Comment: Of course @JonSkeet, read my comment again. *String.IsNullorEmpty will avoid OP passing as object* OP has to convert it anyway to `String`, then there will not be a bug hard to find due to reference comparison.

Comment: @Stijn, 99% of the time, yes. I'm not claiming I never use the debugger, but it's my tool of last resort.

Comment: @Matthew, I completely disagree. I'd say that "o really understand HOW code words rather than just if it DOES work - and indeed how it doesn't work if the unit test fails - there's no substitute for single-stepping all new code in a debugger" is actually the bollocks claim. Each to their own, I guess...

Comment: *"The values are truly empty"* clearly they're not. *"It is in a razor webpage"* you can put breakpoints in your view. *`foreach (var row1 in db.Query(querypeople + order))`* database queries in your view?

Comment: @Stijn Yes, this is all displaying data from a database

Comment: @stijn What is wrong with my question? I understand if statements, but this is not working as it should. The specific issue is described. What else must I have?

Comment: @HarrisonGibbs If it's not working as it should, then the variables don't have the values you think they have, simple as that. We cannot help you with that. What we could help with is something like *"I fill my variables like this, and I expect them to have value X and Y, but they don't"*.

Comment: @Stijn alright, I will test my variables to make sure they are working correctly. Thanks for the help, I will keep this in mind for future questions!

Answer (score 2):

If it is going to the else/else, then both selectedlocat and selectedfield are not equal to "". Have you checked if they are null?

Comment: The idea is that they will either be empty or have a value that I posted in a dropdown form earlier in this page. If I selected a value, the it will go to the else, but if it is empty, it will follow the if to the next statement.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your logic. You can use `string.Trim()` function to remove any white-space characters in case if they have any. (if you wan't to take white spaces as a zero length string)

```
if (selectedlocat.Trim() == "")
{
    if (selectedfield.Trim() == "")
    { 
    }else{ 
    }
}
else
{
    if (selectedfield.Trim() == "")
    { 
    }else{ 
    }
}
```

Depending on your requirement, you could also use **[String.IsNullOrEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)** or **[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)** methods

Comment: look at my comment on the other answer